# Is there a way to join the roots of bones?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

I'm learning armatures and trying to rig a model with a basic rig by extruding bones.

I think I made a mistake however as the legs are separate from the body.

Is there a way to join the roots back together or do I have to redo that part of the rig?

I've already parented the mesh parts to the bones so I'd prefer not to start again.

Comment: Joining the roots is not allowed, you can parent them to the same bone so that roots will be joined.

Answer (score 1):

Select the armature, go to edit mode, select the child bones, shift select the parent bone and press Ctrl P (keep offset, if it's not a connected chain).

Generally legs are child of the Hip bone.

Mesh binding will not be affected by the operation.

Comment: Thanks mate, I'll give that a try